# Write a certain hex pattern to a file from bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, memory

I am trying to do some memory tests and am trying to write a certain hex pattern to a regular file from bash. How would I go about doing this without using the xxd or hexdump tool/command?

Thanks, 
Neco

Comment: could you provide an example of what exactly do you want to print

Comment: What I should probably mention is that by writing out the hex pattern I am trying to turn certain memory bits on and off in a certain fashion. So I'm essentially trying to write a pattern like 0101001010001, check if the patten is properly written and then rewrite another pattern like 101111100111 and see if that pattern was properly written to a memory location currently occupied by a file. Is it possible to do that via bash?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest thing is probably:

```
printf '\xde\xad\xbe\xef' > file
```

but it is often more convenient to do

```
perl -e 'print pack "H*", "deadbeef"' > file
```

Comment: `echo -e` works this way too. `echo -e "\xde\xad\xbe\xef"` Probably want `echo -en` actually.

Answer (score 4):

If I get your question correctly printf should do:

```
>printf %X 256
100
```

Comment: He wants to emit raw hex into a file, not just an ASCII numerical representation of hex.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `od -x` instead? That's pretty universaly available, od has been around since the dawn of time[1]

[1] Not really the dawn of time.

Comment: What I should probably mention is that by writing out the hex pattern I am trying to turn certain memory bits on and off in a certain fashion. If I have a file open and I use od to write out to an already existent file will the data be written to the same memory locations?

Comment: Are you trying to write to /dev/mem or something? Maybe you should try describing what you actually want to do. Sounds like you want to write some raw bytes, not (ASCII) hex.

Comment: So I'm essentially trying to write a pattern like 0101001010001, check if the patten is properly written and then rewrite another pattern like 101111100111 and see if that pattern was properly written to a memory location currently occupied by a file. Is it possible to do that via bash?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this in bash one of the way is 
\x31
'\' is used to skip next charcter from bash decoding 
'x' show its a hex number

```
echo -en \\x31\\x32\\x33 > test
```

-e to avoid trailing line (else 0x0A will apend at end) 
-n to interprete backslash escapes

Answer (score 0):

Memory testing is *much* more complex subject than just writing / reading patterns in memory. Memory testing puts pretty hard limits on what a testing program can do and what state the whole system is in. Technically, it's impossible to test 100% of memory when you're running regular OS at all.

On the other hand, you can run some real test program from a shell, or schedule test execution on next boot with some clever hacking around. You might want to take a look at how it's done in Inquisitor, i.e. [running memtester for in-OS testing](http://www.inquisitor.ru/doc/tests/memory.html) and [scheduling memtest86* run on next boot](https://inq.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/inq/trunk/client/test/boot_from_image).

If you absolutely must remain in your current booted OS, then probably memtester would be your tool of choice - although note that it's not very precise memory test.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of suggestions of using printf and echo, but there's one tiny difference. Printf is not capable of producing zeros (binary zeros), while echo does the job properly. Consider these examples:

```
printf "\x31\x32\x00\x33\x00\x00\x00\x34">printf.txt
echo -en "\x31\x32\x00\x33\x00\x00\x00\x34">echo.txt
```

As a result, printf.txt has a size of 3 bytes (yep, it writes the first zero and stops). And the echo.txt is 8 bytes long and contains actual data.